# Select rows from a transactions table and also return 0 values in case of missing data

Tags: sqlite

I have developed a small app using SQLite that is used to track expenses. In this app I have the following table:

```
--------------------------
date | expense | value
--------------------------
2024-01-01 | Food | 25.99
2024-01-19 | Food | 4.99
2024-01-01 | Apple | 9.99
2024-01-10 | Phone | 15.99
2024-03-10 | Food | 20.00
...
```

I have used a query in the past to get a summary of all expenses by type, month and year like the following:

```
SELECT 
    expense, 
    sum(value) as balance, 
    strftime("%m", valuationdate) as month, strftime("%Y", valuationdate) as year
FROM Transactions
group by expense, month, year
order by expense, year, month;


--------------------------
month | year | expense | value
--------------------------
01 | 2024 | Food | 30.98
01 | 2024 | Apple | 9.99
01 | 2024 | Phone | 15.99
03 | 2024 | Food | 20.00
...
```

As of today this was sufficient for my small app.  Now I want to enhance the app and draw a graph using chart.js, but unfortunately the chart is drawn wrong due to missing data. This happens when there are no rows for particular expenses in particular months, e. g. no food expenses in Feb 2024, but then expenses again in March 2024.

My aim is query the table again and modify my query statement to return also rows for missing expense types and months and also return the value of 0 then. So regarding the example above, there is the following row missing due to missing data:

```
--------------------------
month | year | expense | value
--------------------------
02 | 2024 | Food | 0
...
```

I googled a bit and found that CTE might be the solution to my problem but I am still having problems writing the right SQL statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a calendar table approach.  Use one table which contains all dates to appear in the report, and another which contains all expenses.

```sql
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT strftime("%m", VALUATIONDATE) AS month,
                    strftime("%Y", VALUATIONDATE) AS year
    FROM Transactions
),
expenses AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT expense
    FROM Transactions
)

SELECT 
    e.expense, 
    COALESCE(SUM(t.value), 0) AS balance,
    d.month,
    d.year
FROM dates d
CROSS JOIN expenses e
LEFT JOIN Transactions t
    ON d.month = strftime("%m", t.VALUATIONDATE) AND
       d.year = strftime("%Y", t.VALUATIONDATE) AND
       t.expense = e.expense
GROUP BY e.expense, d.month, d.year
ORDER BY e.expense, d.year, d.month;
```